# Pandas add missing value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new with Pandas, looking for a method to add missing value in the dataframe.
any idea how to produce from the input to output? Thanks

```
Input 

      Module  Status  Domain
0        1    N      www.cat.com
1        2    N      www.cat.com
2        5    Y      www.cat.com
3        7    Y      www.cat.com
4        8    Y      www.cat.com
5        9    N      www.cat.com

Expected 

      Module  Status  Domain
0        1    N      www.cat.com
1        2    N      www.cat.com
2        5    Y      www.cat.com
3        7    Y      www.cat.com
4        8    Y      www.cat.com
5        9    N      www.cat.com
6        3    N      www.cat.com
7        4    N      www.cat.com
8        6    N      www.cat.com
```

Comment: I haven't found anything work so far, the new value is fixed (Status: N, Domain: www.cat.com), but only the module will be added (for example range of 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reindexing option:

```py
df = df.set_index('Module') \
    .reindex(np.arange(df["Module"].min(), df["Module"].max() + 1)) \
    .fillna(pd.Series(['N', 'www.cat.com'], index=['Status', 'Domain'])) \
    .reset_index()
print(df)
```

```
   Module Status       Domain
0       1      N  www.cat.com
1       2      N  www.cat.com
2       3      N  www.cat.com
3       4      N  www.cat.com
4       5      Y  www.cat.com
5       6      N  www.cat.com
6       7      Y  www.cat.com
7       8      Y  www.cat.com
8       9      N  www.cat.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
mn, mx = df["Module"].min(), df["Module"].max()
missing = list(set(df["Module"]).symmetric_difference(range(mn, mx + 1)))

df = (
    pd.concat(
        [df, pd.DataFrame({"Module": missing, "Status": "N", "Domain": np.nan})]
    )
    .ffill()
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Module Status       Domain
0       1      N  www.cat.com
1       2      N  www.cat.com
2       5      Y  www.cat.com
3       7      Y  www.cat.com
4       8      Y  www.cat.com
5       9      N  www.cat.com
6       3      N  www.cat.com
7       4      N  www.cat.com
8       6      N  www.cat.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of Module column and using loop match with expected list to be present and create another dataframe when the no is not match. After then merge the two dataframe

Comment: Thanks, but is there any Pandas function available? something similar to .resample or .ffill ?

Comment: Pandas function are there to handle missing values with in a dataframe but you're trying to add new rows in our dataframe that can't be expected

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
status = set(range(1,10)) - set(df['Module'])
df.append(pd.DataFrame([df[df['Status']=='N'].iloc[0]]*len(status)).assign(Module=status)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
#    Module Status       Domain
# 0       1      N  www.cat.com
# 1       2      N  www.cat.com
# 2       5      Y  www.cat.com
# 3       7      Y  www.cat.com
# 4       8      Y  www.cat.com
# 5       9      N  www.cat.com
# 6       3      N  www.cat.com
# 7       4      N  www.cat.com
# 8       6      N  www.cat.com
```